# Converting array objects into json in react

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object

I have two array objects and need to use those two arrays in a json object. How to achieve it in react?

```
let qn = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
let ans= [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false];
```

I need to convert the above two arrays below like this for the purpose of database insertion.

```
options: [{qn: "1", ans: false}, {qn: "2", ans: false}, ....., {qn: "10", ans: false}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `map` with index

```js
let qn = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
let ans = [false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true]

const res = {
  options: qn.map((q, index) => ({
    qn: q,
    ans: ans[index],
  })),
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: let text = this.props.data.matrix.options;
    let userAnswer = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < text.length; j++) {
      userAnswer.push(false);
    }
    const options = this.props.data.matrix.options.map((t, index) => ({
      text: t,
      userAnswer: userAnswer[index],
    }));
    console.log(options);

Comment: Your comment on this question has helped me a lot, but I need one more information.

Comment: I'm getting options: [{text: {text: "1"}, userAnswer: false}].... Instead of this format, I need like this : options: [{text:  "1", userAnswer: false}].

Comment: @SureshKumarPasupulati you should use `text: t.text` instead of `text: t`, full:  `const options = this.props.data.matrix.options.map((t, index) => ({ text: t.text, userAnswer: userAnswer[index], }))`

Comment: I'm glad that you helped me  instantly....Thank you so much! @hgb123